# Check if date is the same as previous date. If not echo out statement PHP

Tags: php

I don't know the correct syntax to use if i wanted to check if the date is the same as the previous date in a table

I want to echo out a statement if it isnt the same date

I have this statement that gets the difference, how would i produce a statement that checked if there was a difference and echo'd out a string if it was

```
  $interval = $newdate->diff(new DateTime($last_date));
```

Thanks guys, sorry i can't provide much code im struggling with syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `$last_date` and `$newdate` are both [DateTime](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) objects you can do a comparison as of PHP 5.2

```
if ($last_date == $newdate){
    echo "They're equal";
} else {
    echo "They're not equal";
}
```

Comment: perfect,  this is my application http://ignitethatdesign.com/CheckFilm/test_search.php im getting this response now. how could i manipulate it so that the first "the same date as above" is displayed but the following 2 aren't?

Comment: I'd need to see more code. You may want to make it a separate question so others can help out, too.